# Converting Carriage Return to HTML Break

Tags: python, django, replace, carriage-return

I am importing an xml file of blog posts into Django.

Part of this process requires me to convert escaped html characters back to their html form by using replace:

```
s = s.replace("&lt;", "<")
```

My problem is that the xml file, when viewed with vim, contains carriage returns in the form of "^M" -- I'd like to convert these carriage returns to break tags, but

```
s = s.replace("^M", "<br />")
```

does nothing.

I tried converting all of these tags in the xml file with vim, but then my minidom importer breaks.

Any idea on how I can accomplish this conversion using replace?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using one or both of these should work:

```
s = s.replace("\r\n", "<br />")
s = s.replace("\n", "<br />")
```

Comment: This is even better: `'<br />'.join(thatLine.splitlines())`. See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines