# handling newline characters like "\n" and "\r\n" from an python error message in an html file

Tags: python, html, flask, line-breaks, extract-error-message

I want to show the a FormatViolationError (or error's of other types) to the user. Therefore I programmed a flask webserver that returns the error message in an html file to the user.

The output of the error message has multiple linebreaks included. I want to display these linebreaks to the user but in the html.

Example error:
`FormatViolationError - description=Payload for Action is syntactically incorrect or structure for Action, details={'cause': "Payload '{'status': 'Accept'}' for action 'GetCertificateStatus' is not valid: 'Accept' is not one of ['Accepted', 'Failed']\n\nFailed validating 'enum' in schema['properties']['status']:\n    {'additionalProperties': False,\n     'description': 'This indicates whether the charging station was able '\n                    'to retrieve the OCSP certificate status.\\r\\n',\n`

The error includes many newline characters as `'\n'` or `'\r\n'`. My idea was to replace them with `'<br>'`.

I have the following code:

```
def foo():
        try:
            somefunction(bar)
        except Exception as e:
            str_e = repr(e)
            # replace the "python" linebreak with html line breaks
            str_e_with_linebreaks = str_e.replace("\\r", "<br>")
            str_e_with_linebreaks = str_e_with_linebreaks.replace("\\n", "<br>")
            return str_e_with_linebreaks

        return "No errors were found in the provided data"
```

The html that is returned to the user includes the `"<br>"` but doesn't have the desired linebreaks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>String Processor Result</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Result</h1>
         <p>&lt;FormatViolationError - description=Payload for Action is syntactically incorrect or structure for Action, details={&#39;cause&#39;: &#34;Payload &#39;{&#39;status&#39;: &#39;Accept&#39;, &#39;Accept&#39; is not one of [&#39;Accepted&#39;, &#39;Failed&#39;]&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;Failed validating &#39;enum&#39; in schema[&#39;properties&#39;][&#39;status&#39;]:&lt;br&gt;    {&#39;additionalProperties&#39;: False,&lt;br&gt;     &#39;description&#39;: &#39;This indicates whether the charging station was able &#39;&lt;br&gt;                    &#39;to retrieve the OCSP certificate status.\&lt;br&gt;\&lt;br&gt;&#39;,&lt;br&gt;     &#39;enum&#39;: [&#39;Accepted&#39;, &#39;Failed&#39;],&lt;br&gt;     &#39;javaType&#39;: &#39;GetCertificateStatusEnum&#39;,&lt;br&gt;     &#39;type&#39;: &#39;string&#39;}&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;On instance[&#39;status&#39;]:&lt;br&gt;    &#39;Accept&#39;&#34;, &#39;ocpp_message&#39;: &lt;CallResult - unique_id=8c5f1ba7-0167-4ef3-95cd-6efd88a6720f, action=GetCertificateStatus, payload={&#39;status&#39;: &#39;Accept&#39;}&gt;}&gt;</p>
    <a href="/">Back to input form</a>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

I am stuck. Most likely replacing the characters is not the way to go. How can I nicely format the error message and include it in an html?

In the actual app.py (flask web server). I include the returned error in the html with:

```
result = foo(data)
return render_template('result.html', result=result)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10261870/converting-carriage-return-to-html-break

Comment: not a python dev but can't you use <code><pre> (the pre is what you want, code is for styling)? Also it seems weird that you would replace both \r and \n - you should either replace a singular \n or a \r\n, which regex would be nice to use for. Your escapes also look funny, should you even escape \r? why not use  "\r"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting Carriage Return to HTML Break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10261870/converting-carriage-return-to-html-break)

Answer (score 0):

You are using repr with generates a printable representational string of the given object.

When you use `<br>` in your string, it gets converted to `&lt;br&gt;`. These `&lt;` and `&gt;` represent the ascii < and > characters so they can be used in an html string without being recognised as tag. Kinda like how we use the \ in `\n` in python.

A solution would be to first convert to the printable representational string using repr, and after that you replace the `&lt;br&gt;` by `<br>` using
`String.replace("&lt;br&gt;",  "<br>")`

It does look like that mean you cannot use the `repr(e)` because that messes up the code.